# How can I escape from PHP code inside Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

```
var i = 1; 
$("#add_row").click(function(){

    var arr = "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='counter' value='" + i + "'><input type='hidden' id='pd-id-" + i + "' name='pd-id-" + i + "'><input autocomplete='off' type='text' id='pd-search-" + i + "' class='hahaha'><ul style='width: 44.8vw' class='livesearch' id='pd-result-" + i + "' onclick='clickResult()'></ul></td><td><input type='text' required name='workdescription-" + i + "'></td><td><select></select></td><?php

    $date = new DateTime();

    $y=1;


    if (date('d') < '18' AND date('d') > '2') {
        for ($x = 1 ; $x <= 16 ; $x++) {
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='hr-" . i . "-" . $x . "'></td>";
        }
    } else if (date('d') < '3') {
        for ($x = 16 ; $x <= date('t', strtotime(date('Y-m')." -1 month")) ; $x++) {
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='hr-" . i . "-" . $y . "'></td>";
            $y++;
        }
    } else {

        for ($x = 16 ; $x <= date('t') ; $x++) {
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='hr-" . i . "-" . $y . "'></td>";
            $y++;
        }

    }

    $i++;

    ?></tr>"
    ;

    i++;

    $( "#tablebody" ).append(arr);
});
```

I need to escape the letter i inside the echo of the PHP. I want them to have the value of the javascript variable i at the top. How may I do this? Also is there a better way to do this?

Comment: and where is the `arr` variable?

Comment: Why you use php inside a javascript / jquery function? I see no need for this. Javascript got its own DateTime object and for loops. You can solve your issue with javascript only.

Comment: Well if the client side's date is wrong then this would also be wrong. I want the date only gotten from the server side. for accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in a comment above, there 's no need for PHP in this case. You can solve it with Javascript only. To answer your question correctly, here 's a possible solution with Javascript and PHP.

```
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>

    </tr>
</table>

<template id="my-template">
    <td><input type="text" name=""></td>
</template>

<script>
    var day = '<?= (new DateTime())->format('d') ?>',
        daysOfMonth = '<?= (new DateTime())->format('t') ?>',
        daysOfMonthOneMonthBefore = '<?= (new DateTime('-1 month'))->format('t') ?>',
        template = document.getElementById('my-template'),
        i = 1,
        y = 1;

    var positiveInt = new Number(day),
        positiveIntOneMOnthBefore = new Number(daysOfMonthOneMonthBefore),
        inputElement = template.content.querySelector('input');

    if (positiveInt < 18 && positiveInt > 2) {
        for (var x = 1; x <= 16; x++) {
            inputElement.name = 'hr-' + i + '-' x;
            var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
            document.querySelector('#my-table tr').appendChild(clone);
        }
    } else if (positiveInt < 3) {
        for (var x = 16; x <= positiveIntOneMOnthBefore; x++) {
            inputElement.name = 'hr-' + i + '-' + y;
            y++;

            var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
            document.querySelector('#my-table tr').appendChild(clone);
        }
    } else {
        for (var x = 16; x <= positiveInt; x++) {
            inputElement.name = 'hr-' + i + '-' + y;
            y++;

            var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
            document.querySelector('#my-table tr').appendChild(clone);
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you said you need only the actual date from the server. The rest of the code is done with native javascript. You don t even need jQuery for this. This code example is not tested. This code uses HTML5 elements like the `template` tag. Make sure you are using the right HTML5 doctype. Beside that it should show you a possible way how to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try your echos like this:

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='hr-' + i + '-" . $x . "'></td>";
```

Remember that all the php code gets completely parsed server-side. Javascript is client side. Don't confuse javascript and php syntax. Concating with `.` is php, `+` is the javascript equivalent. Also use quotes consistently. E.g. `"` in php and `'` in javascript. If you need `"` in Javascript, escape it like so: `\"`.